# square root of complex numbers in scheme

Tags: math, scheme, racket, complex-numbers

```
 (define (make-complex a b) (cons a b))
 (define (real x) (car x))
 (define (imag x) (cdr x))
 (define (complex-sqrt x)
     (define (first a b) (sqrt (/ (+ a
                              (sqrt (+
                                     (* a a)
                                     (* b b))))
                           2)))
     (define (second a b) (sqrt (/ (+ (* -1 a)
                               (sqrt (+
                                      (* a a)
                                      (* b b))))
                            2)))
  (cons (first (real x) (imag x)) (second (real x) (imag x))))
  (complex-sqrt (make-complex 2 0))
  (complex-sqrt (make-complex -3 0))
```

So for some context, this function finds the square root of a complex number. a is the real part of the complex number and b is the imaginary part. The complex-sqrt function is not suppose to work for some values of b=0 but i'm not sure why. I tried several values of a where b equals 0 and put them into my calculator but they both give me the same answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The implemented formula is wrong for negative `b` since the square of

```
sqrt( (sqrt(a*a+b*b)+a)/2 ) +i*sqrt( (sqrt(a*a+b*b)-a)/2 )
```

is

```
a + i*sqrt( (a*a+b*b) - a*a) = a + i*abs(b)
```

which is then not the original number.

---

For `b=0` the term `sqrt(a*a)` might produce a number slightly smaller than `abs(a)`, so that one of real and imaginary part has a negative expression under the outer square root.

Comment: How would I be able to fix it?

Comment: Also, do you know any values of a where b equals 0 that wouldn't work for this code?

Comment: something along the lines of `if b<0 then imag = -imag`.

Comment: And no, I am not aware of such numbers, but a very sloppy implementation of `sqrt` could in theory produce such results.